# How to improve subpixel hinting in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

This is Windows 7:

[image]

And this is Linux:

[image]

To me the font in Windows looks reddish, while the font in Linux color-neutral even though they both have subpixel hinting enabled. How to make the font in Windows look like in Linux?

Comment: Hi Anixx,
 
I've examined the two screenshots you have posted at 1000% magnification, but I can't see *much* difference.  I also don't know if screenshots can capture sub-pixel rendering, maybe someone can clarify?

Can you clarify some details?
- Are these physical, or virtual machines? If so, what is hosting them and how are you accessing them? (e.g, is Linux a VM inside Windows 8? Are they both VMs inside ESXi, etc? Are you accessing Windows using RDP, and Linux with VNC?  Is it a dual-boot computer with 2 different O/S?) 
- Are you using the same monitor on both machines?

Comment: try the ClearType Tuner from Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

These are found in several places in the Registry:

- FontSmoothing
- FontSmoothingGamma
- FontSmoothingOrientation
- FontSmoothingType

For example `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`:

For `FontSmoothing` key

- Value "0" or "1": disables font smoothing
- Value "2": enables font smoothing

For `FontSmoothingType` key

- Value "0" or "1": switch to gray font smoothing
- Value "2": switch to colored font smoothing

For `FontSmoothingGamma` key

- Value between 0 to 2200 decimal: Intensity of color. 0=dark, 2200=light

For `FontSmoothingOrientation` key

- Value "0": CRT (Value "1" and "2" are LCD)
- Value "1": RGB format (red, green, blue), normal
- Value "2": BGR format (blue, green, red)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment above.  Have you tried adjusting the ClearType settings in Windows?

Go to Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalisation -> Adjust ClearType Settings (in the Fonts section).  It will go through and present you with some examples of fonts and you have to choose which one looks best, kind of like an eye exam!

You can also edit the settings in the registry at:

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\
```

There are 4 registry entries in there,

```
-FontSmoothing
-FontSmoothingGamma
-FontSmoothingOrientation
-FontSmoothingType
```

Have a look at here for some information on the registry entries: http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/538-enabling-cleartype-in-vista/

I suspect that there is no combination of registry that cannot be achieved by using the GUI method I mentioned earlier.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

If you are not satisfied with ClearType there's also the option to install FreeType on Windows. I have no experience with it though.